# FtpWebRequest Upload out-of-memory

Tags: ftpwebrequest

I'm using the example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx
to upload a large 1GB file to an FTP server. However it chokes on the line:

```
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
```

with an out-of-memory exception. Is there a way to stream the file from disk directly to the FTP server without reading all of it to memory at once? I expect that I can chunk it and send it bit by bit but I would have thought that I would be able to point the read stream at the write stream...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can *try* simply writing to the request stream in chunks - if you're using .NET 4, `Stream.CopyTo` will make this really easy:

```
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    using (Stream output = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        input.CopyTo(output);
    }
}
```

You might want to look at `FtpWebRequest`'s documentation to see if there's anything about buffering - basically you want to disable any buffering that's there.

(On a side note, it's a shockingly poor example in MSDN, in terms of resource handling without `using` statements. Ick.)

Answer (score 3):

Generally, what you would do is write a loop that:

1. Reads a chunk from the `sourceStream` (something like 16 kB is reasonable)
2. Writes that chunk to the `requestStream`
3. If not at the end of the input, go back to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Greg. I didn't try it because Jon's worked the first time but it looks like a good alternative.

Comment: Jon's suggestion does the same thing as I said, inside `CopyTo` :)